# Results of DecisionTreeClassifier differ between Spark 2 and Spark 3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, decision-tree, spark3, spark2

I trained a decision tree model on the same data using the same parameters with Spark 2 and Spark 3.

```
pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier
tree_md = DecisionTreeClassifier(maxBins=500,maxDepth=6, seed=0)
```

I obtained a different result of decision tree model. Could you tell me if this is normal?

Thanks,

Comment: This answer is relevant. The algo inside might have been changed. https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/11576/are-decision-tree-learning-algorithms-deterministic  But does it matter in your usecase?

Comment: Normally I set the seed to 0 to avoid tree hazards.